# tripcolor using RGB values for each vertex

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a 2D triangle mesh with n vertices that is stored in a variable `tri` (a matplotlib.tri.Triangulation object); I can plot the mesh with matplotlib's tripcolor function easily enough and everything works fine. However, I also have (r,g,b) triples for each vertex (`vcolors`), and these values do not fall along a single dimension thus can't be easily converted to a color-map (for example, imagine if you overlaid a triangle mesh on a large photo of a park, then assigned each vertex the color of the pixel beneath it).

I thought I would be able to do something like this:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor(tri, vcolors)
```

> ValueError: Collections can only map rank 1 arrays

Is there a convenient way to convert a `vcolors`-like (n x 3) matrix into something usable by tripcolor? Is there an alternative to tripcolor that accepts vertex colors?

One thing I have tried is to make my own colormap:

```
z = numpy.asarray(range(len(vcolors)), dtype=np.float) / (len(vcolors) - 1)
cmap = matplotlib.colors.Colormap(vcolors, N=len(vcolors))
matplotlib.pyplot.tripcolor(tri, z, cmap=cmap)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

This however did nothing---no figure appears and no error is raised; the function returns a figure handle but nothing ever gets rendered (I'm using an IPython notebook). Note that if I call the following, a plot appears just fine:

```
tripcolor(tri, np.zeros(len(vcolors)))
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it obviously did not help. To prevent further confusions: If you want gouraud shading, mention it in the question. Because tripcolor does not allow Gouraud shading in conjunction with the `facecolors` argument there is no solution to your question, other than  using a colormap. If the number of different colors is limited, a possible solution might be to create a custom colormap, e.g. if you only have 255 different color values, you could create a colormap of those 255 values.

Comment: Gouraud shading is a plus, but I don't require it. With or without gouraud shading, your assertion that the `facecolors` argument could solve this problem seems false: it still requires a 1D z-vector that is interpreted according to the colormap. It doesn't help me go from an RGB triple per vertex to something usable. My question asks for an alternative to `tripcolor` that can handle this case, so I disagree that no solution is possible. It also explicitly points out that the custom colormap solution fails, so if you have a workaround, I'd love to hear it (number of colors is `len(vcolors)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rooting around in `matplotlib`'s `tripcolor` and `Colormap` code, I came up with the following solution, which seems to work only as long as one uses 'gouraud' shading (otherwise, it does a very poor job of deducing the face colors; see below).

The trick is to create a colormap that, when given `n` evenly spaced numbers between `0` and `1` (inclusive) reproduces the original array of colors:

```
def colors_to_cmap(colors):
    '''
    colors_to_cmap(nx3_or_nx4_rgba_array) yields a matplotlib colormap object that, when
    that will reproduce the colors in the given array when passed a list of n evenly
    spaced numbers between 0 and 1 (inclusive), where n is the length of the argument.

    Example:
      cmap = colors_to_cmap(colors)
      zs = np.asarray(range(len(colors)), dtype=np.float) / (len(colors)-1)
      # cmap(zs) should reproduce colors; cmap[zs[i]] == colors[i]
    '''
    colors = np.asarray(colors)
    if colors.shape[1] == 3:
        colors = np.hstack((colors, np.ones((len(colors),1))))
    steps = (0.5 + np.asarray(range(len(colors)-1), dtype=np.float))/(len(colors) - 1)
    return matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap(
        'auto_cmap',
        {clrname: ([(0, col[0], col[0])] + 
                   [(step, c0, c1) for (step,c0,c1) in zip(steps, col[:-1], col[1:])] + 
                   [(1, col[-1], col[-1])])
         for (clridx,clrname) in enumerate(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'alpha'])
         for col in [colors[:,clridx]]},
        N=len(colors))
```

Again, note that `'gouraud'` shading is required for this to work. To demonstrate why this fails, the following code blocks show my particular use case. (I am plotting part of a flattened cortical sheet with a partially transparent data overlay). In this code, there are 40,886 vertices (in `the_map.coordinates`) and 81,126 triangles (in `the_map.indexed_faces`); the `colors` array has shape `(40886, 3)`.

The following code works fine with 'gouraud' shading:

```
tri = matplotlib.tri.Triangulation(the_map.coordinates[0],
                                   the_map.coordinates[1],
                                   triangles=the_map.indexed_faces.T)
cmap = rgbs_to_cmap(colors)
zs = np.asarray(range(the_map.vertex_count), dtype=np.float) / (the_map.vertex_count - 1)
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
plt.tripcolor(tri, zs, cmap=cmap, shading='gouraud')
```

> [image: Plot using Gouraud shading]

But without 'gouraud' shading, the face-colors are perhaps being assigned according to the average of their vertices (have not verified this), which is clearly wrong:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
plt.tripcolor(tri, zs, cmap=cmap)
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way of creating the color map is via [`from_list`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list):

```
z = numpy.arange(n)
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    'mymap', rgb, N=len(rgb)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

While for the `tripcolor` function, use of a colormap is obligatory, the `PolyCollection` and `TriMesh` classes (from `matplotlib.collection`) that it calls internally can deal with RGB color arrays as well. I have used the following code, based on the `tripcolor` source, to draw a triangle mesh with given RGB face colors:

```
tri = Triangulation(...)
colors = nx3 RGB array
maskedTris = tri.get_masked_triangles()
verts = np.stack((tri.x[maskedTris], tri.y[maskedTris]), axis=-1)
collection = PolyCollection(verts)
collection.set_facecolor(colors)
plt.gca().add_collection(collection)
plt.gca().autoscale_view()
```

To set colors per vertex (Gouraud shading), use a `TriMesh` instead (with `set_facecolor`).